# MS Dynamics development on Mac

Tags: macos, dynamics-crm

I have a Macbook with 2GM Ram. I want to do development on Microsoft Dynamics. Is it possible as I will be running Virtual Machine/VMware?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to run a full Dynamics CRM installation (Windows Server 2008, Dynamics CRM, & SQL Server) on a virtual machine I would suggest no less than 4GB of memory assigned to the virtual machine alone to make it useable.

I don't believe a machine with only 2GB of total memory will suffice.